# Underwater: Edit and Join separated layers smoothly

Tags: photo-editing, composition, effect, layers, underwater

As I really enjoy underwater photography, I am wondering how does one end up with a final image like the one I share below:

**Unedited on the left, desired effect on the right:**

[image: Original Image] [image: After Edits]

<sub>Source: https://www.instagram.com/p/CApGLcCHStN/</sub>

This edit seems to complex for Lightroom as it doesn't have a [Channel Mixer](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/color-monochrome-adjustments-using-channels.html) so I presume the photographer used Photoshop or GIMP. There one can copy a blue/green channel and convert it to red.

In this case, it seems that the photographer is using two separate layers and adds the people separately, so that he can get a darker background.

Assuming that to get an image like the one shown above the photographer is not only using a pure picture and color grading, but editing multiple layers of underwater images and join them smoothly, how does one edit and join edited layers, from underwater images, in a subtle way?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Photo.SE! It seems to be you have already quite an idea on how to do this (convert blue/green channel to red, use Tint, use two separate layers), so I was wondering what your actual question is. Could you perhaps clarify that by editing your question?

Comment: I would like to know how does one end up with an image like the one shown above after effects: Is it only pure picture and color grading, two separate layers,...? Tools/techniques to support the answer may help as well.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you could describe the effect in words (see [this meta post as well](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/)) and
edit this post accordingly. Make sure to use a descriptive title, 
too. Perhaps you can also show some previous research? What did you find when e.g. browsing the [`[underwater]`](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/underwater) tag? Thank you!

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke thanks a lot for sharing that meta post.
I have tried to clarify what I mean by effect. If one goes deeper in the question, it seems that what I am trying to figure out is how to edit and join multiple underwater layers smoothly (like the one shown in the image above). Let me know if it is clearer.

Comment: Thanks, it's more clear now what your question is. I've removed some distracting parts about Lightroom editing from your question, hope that's ok. Only one thing: can you please describe in words that what you're looking for instead of just `like the image below`. Do you like the darkened skin tone? The conversion of green to dark blue of the surroundings? Etc...

Answer (score 3):

> Is this only pure picture and color grading?

The image has obviously been heavily edited in Photoshop or similar.

- **The background has been entirely replaced**.
- Part of the diver's shirt has been removed.
- The luminosity of the fins has been altered.
- The colors in the final image have very little hue variation.

> How does one end up with an image like the one shown... ?

The Channel Mixer is unlikely to be useful in this case.  Techniques involved likely include:

- **"Hand coloring."** – Try using color layer blending.
- Background replacement. – Try using layer masks.
- The usual essential photo editing tools: levels, curves, cloning, layer blending, masks, etc.

Writing a tutorial covering all of these techniques is overly expansive.  There are plenty of tutorials online.  Consider asking Google or YouTube.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. What I want to know is parameters/techniques to consider when composing (joining smoothly) layers of edited underwater images (like the one I shared). On your answer you refere the little hue varietion, playing with the luminosity, and some more.